# Flask upload file to static folder "static/avatars"

Tags: python, flask

I have one problem during I try to upload photo to app/static/avatars folder in python flask.

my folder structure:

```
Project/
       app/
           static/
                 avatars/
           Upload/
                 upload.py
```

my destination folder is "avatars" and my codes is in "Upload/upload.py" How could I get realpath to upload?

Sample codes

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER                       =   'app/static/avatars/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS                  =   set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']         =   UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']    =   1 * 600 * 600
```

Error Message:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'//app/static/avatars/002.png'
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you check if the dirs in the path exist?

Comment: Yep, I already create dir "avatars" in static folder @TimoH

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in `upload.py` you could do something like

```
>>> import os
>>> absolute_path = os.path.abspath("../"+UPLOAD_FOLDER+file_name)
```

`os.path.abspath` returns the absolute path from the given relative path, starting in your current working directory.